# Can't install Linux Headers (Kali Linux)

Tags: apt, linux-kernel, kali-linux

I am trying to install Linux headers for Kali Linux on my machine and I have tried every possible solution on the internet but it always show "Unable to locate packages "

```
root@kali:/usr/sbin# apt-get install linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-amd64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-amd64
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-amd64'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-amd64'
```

Here is my sources.list file :

```
# Regular Repositories
deb http://http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main contrib non-free
# Source repositories
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
deb-src http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main contrib non-free
```

Uname -a output :

```
root@kali:/usr/sbin# uname -a
Linux kali 4.6.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.6.4-1kali1 (2016-07-21) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: The Debian Tag "Questions specific to the Debian official distribution (stable, testing, or unstable); if you are using a derivative of Debian (e.g. Mint, Ubuntu, Kali, etc), then use that distribution’s tag instead."  instead of, not as well...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The package `linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-amd64` is no longer available on the regularly kali-linux repository, it should be upgraded to the `4.8.x` version.

update your `/etc/apt/sources.list` : see [Kali sources.list Repositories](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories)

List the available linux-headers and linux-image through `apt-cache search` :

```
apt update 
apt-cache search linux-headers
```

Then install the correct package e,g ( this is an example , it depends on the previous output command) :

```
apt-get install linux-headers-4.8.0-kali1-amd64
```

also run;

```
apt-cache search linux-image
```

install it:

```
apt-get install linux-image-4.8.0-kali1-amd64
```

Reboot your system.

Or you can use the following command to upgrade you kernel to the latest available version and install the appropriate kernel headers:

```
apt update
apt dist-upgrade
reboot
apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: will this reinstall Linux ? I'm having the same issue inside a kali linux distribution in a virtualbox vm

Comment: @mounaim It installs linux headers which are required to upgrade kernel.

Comment: Just tried this, apt-cache search linux-image gives me 4.6.0 versions?

Comment: Check your `sources.list` you should have `deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free` then update & upgrade your package

Answer (score 0):

So, due to lack of resources to support old system maintenance, most of the companies are moving on. So should you. Just [download a new version  of Kali Linux](https://www.kali.org/downloads) and avoid all these headaches. Besides, you have all the bugs patched and many issues solved. Unless you want to do some hacking and create alternatives to the repositories.  Good luck.